# How can I replace a form_for with a link_to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I feel like I'm abusing form_for (and simple_form_for) to update a single hidden attribute of a record. Here is an example:

```
<%= simple_form_for :present, url: present_path(list_item), method: 'put' do |f| %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :ordered, value: "1" %>
    <%= f.button :submit, "ordered", class: "btn btn-mini" %>
<% end %>
```

Essentially this presents a single button that a user can press to mark a `present` as 'ordered'. On the back end, it updates the attribute `:ordered` to the value `1` for the current `list_item`.

I feel like this is a cheat because its not a proper `form` per se. I'd much rather have a single `link_to` which would when clicked updated the attribute.

I imagine the `link_to` would need to be `method:` aware to update the attribute.

Is it possible to replace my `simple_form_for` with a single `link_to`?

Comment: And, in addition to the answer, make it a `remote: true` form and make it an in-place toggle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using:

```
link_to 'Ordered', present_path(list_item, present: {ordered: 1}), method: :put
```

Answer (score 2):

it is, use

```
link_to 'Ordered', present_path(list_item, ordered: 1), method: :put
```

Comment: Interesting- the link is valid and I am seeing this in my logs: Started PUT "/presents/9?ordered=1" but alas, the attribute is not updated.